# Error while uploading file to S3 aws sdk cpp

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, visual-studio-2019, aws-sdk-cpp

so I am trying to upload a local file to aws s3 using the aws sdk cpp.
Here is the sample code that I took from an issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989720/upload-an-image-file-takes-too-long-on-aws-s3-c-sdk)

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/HashingUtils.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace Aws::S3::Model;
using namespace std;
using namespace Aws::Utils;

 static const char* KEY = "try.txt";
 static const char* BUCKET = "bucket-name";

 int main()
 {
Aws::SDKOptions options;
Aws::InitAPI(options);

Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration myConf;
myConf.region = Aws::Region::US_EAST_2;
Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(myConf);

const Aws::String bucket_name = BUCKET;
const Aws::String key_name = KEY;
const Aws::String dir_name = "C:/Users/linda.naoui/source/repos/Upload s3";

std::cout << "Uploading " << key_name << " to S3 bucket: " <<
    bucket_name << std::endl;



Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest object_request;
object_request.WithBucket(bucket_name).WithKey(key_name);

auto input_data = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::FStream>(key_name.c_str(), dir_name.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);

object_request.SetBody(input_data);

auto put_object_outcome = s3_client.PutObject(object_request);

if (put_object_outcome.IsSuccess()) {
    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "PutObject error: " <<
        put_object_outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << " " <<
        put_object_outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
}

Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);

return 0;
  }
```

I have a lot of similar errors all related to the dll import, I am installed the aws s3 sdk and aws sdk core using Nuget Package and I am currently on Visual Studio 2019.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectResult::~PutObjectResult(void)" (__imp_??1PutObjectResult@Model@S3@Aws@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Aws::Utils::Outcome >::~Outcome >(void)" (??1?$Outcome@VPutObjectResult@Model@S3@Aws@@V?$AWSError@W4S3Errors@S3@Aws@@@Client@4@@Utils@Aws@@QAE@XZ) Upload s3   C:\Users\linda.naoui\source\repos\Upload s3\Upload s3\S3.obj    1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Aws::InitAPI(struct Aws::SDKOptions const &)" (__imp_?InitAPI@Aws@@YAXABUSDKOptions@1@@Z) referenced in function _main   Upload s3   C:\Users\linda.naoui\source\repos\Upload s3\Upload s3\S3.obj    1

I am not sure if the problem is because the linkage window is empty

[image]

Comment: When having a link error, it's usually a good idea to also show how you link the library,

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, I used nuget to install the sdk's it should link it automatically right?

Comment: What happens if you change it to static linking?

Comment: Okay so now I no longer have dll errors, but I have LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest::PutObjectRequest(void)" (??0PutObjectRequest@Model@S3@Aws@@QEAA@XZ) Upload s3 C:\Users\linda.naoui\source\repos\Upload s3\Upload s3\S3.obj 1                                        They all start with unresolved external symbol

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411546/aws-c-sdk-linker-error-on-visual-studio

Comment: Actually it didn't resolve my problem, I still have                                            
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration::ClientConfiguration(void)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by uninstalling Visual Studio 2019 and using Visual Studio 2017 instead